# can I use codeigniter and redis to store session

Tags: codeigniter, redis

I use codeigniter 3 for my project, and I want to use redis to store session
to use it with nodejs and mysql for real-time notification system

i installed redis on my server and test it with nodejs is work good

Comment: The short answer is 'yes'. There is a php library you will need, but other than that you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for the answer(would help others too) but here's a good link  (https://simplapi.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/php-and-node-js-session-share-redi/)
 that explains serializing and de-serializing session data as json. I have done modification in Codeigniter's library Session_redis_driver.php to encode and decode so I can use it in Nodejs. I'd be glad if someone can validate this code and point any pitfalls or unhandled exceptions.

1. Modification in "read" method

   ```
   public function read($session_id)
   {
   if (isset($this->_redis) && $this->_get_lock($session_id))
   {
       // Needed by write() to detect session_regenerate_id() calls
       $this->_session_id = $session_id;

       $session_data = json_decode($this->_redis->get($this->_key_prefix.$session_id),TRUE);

       is_array($session_data)
           ? $this->_key_exists = TRUE
           : $session_data = '';

       $this->_fingerprint = md5(json_encode($session_data));
                   $tmp = $_SESSION;
                   $_SESSION = $session_data;
                   $new_data = session_encode();
                   $_SESSION = $tmp;
       return $new_data;
   }

   return $this->_fail();
   }
   ```

So far this is working without exceptions.

2. In write method the following changes have been done.

   ```
   if (isset($this->_lock_key))
   {
       $this->_redis->setTimeout($this->_lock_key, 300);
                   $tmp = $_SESSION;
                   session_decode($session_data);
                   $new_data = $_SESSION;
                   $_SESSION = $tmp;
       if ($this->_fingerprint !== ($fingerprint = md5(json_encode($new_data))) OR $this->_key_exists === FALSE)
       {
           if ($this->_redis->set($this->_key_prefix.$session_id, json_encode($new_data), $this->_config['expiration']))
           {
               $this->_fingerprint = $fingerprint;
               $this->_key_exists = TRUE;
               return $this->_success;
           }

           return $this->_fail();
       }

       return ($this->_redis->setTimeout($this->_key_prefix.$session_id, $this->_config['expiration']))
           ? $this->_success
           : $this->_fail();
   }
   ```